# Python Gtk3 Filechooser doesn't close after selection

Tags: python, gtk3

I am working on a python application with a Gtk3 interface and have encountered an issue that I would like some help with. A button click signal runs an 'on_clicked' function which in turn calls a 'filechooser' function. The filechooser function displays a Gtk.FileChooserDialog to select a file and returns the selected filepath. Then the 'on_clicked' function performs an action which takes some time to complete.

My issue is that the FileChooserDialog remains open and inactive until the 'on_clicked' function completes the time-consuming action.

Sample code:

```
def on_clicked(self, widget):
    print("selecting file") #This prints out okay
    filepath = self.filechooser()
    print(filepath) #The filepath is printed even though the dialog remains open.
    # Do something that takes several seconds to complete
    time.sleep(10) # FileChooserDialog remains open for 10 seconds
    # At this point the dialog closes.
    print("Wake Up Charlie!")
```

What I would like is for the FileChooserDialog to close when the filechooser function calls dialog.destroy(), rather than after the on_clicked function that calls it has completed its activity. I have tried calling the time-consuming activity in a different thread but the FileChooserDialog still remained open until the activity was completed.

```
    def on_clicked(self, widget):
        print("selecting file")
        filepath = self.filechooser()
        #self.take_time(filepath)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.taking_time(filepath))
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        # the taking_time function completes as expected but the FileChooserDialog stays open while it is running.
```

Any assistance to clarify what I am doing  wrong here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `threading.Thread(target=self.taking_time(filepath))`, you are NOT passing the function object.  Instead, you are CALLING the function.  It will run in-line, taking up real time, and the return from that function is passed to `Thread`.  You need to set `target=self.taking_time` with `args=[filepath]`.

```
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.taking_time, args=[filepath])
```